# How to avoid VsCode Prettier to break chain functions with arrow functions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm working with VSCode and Prettier and when we have chained functions call with arrow functions inside like a lodash chain:

```
let total = _(credits).filter(c => c.active).sumBy(c => c.fee);
```

Prettier breaks into:

```
discount = _(credits)
    .filter(c => c.active)
    .sumBy(c => c.fee);
```

When the we use `strings` insteads arrow functions, it does not breaks into several lines, for instance:

```
let total = _(credits).filter('c => c.active').sumBy('c => c.fee');
```

I'm working with following `.prettierrc` and `"prettier": "^2.0.5"`:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "printWidth": 280,
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
}
```

How can I avoid the line breaking with prettier when there is a arrow function inside the functions?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to override method chain breaking behaviour. With version 2.0, Prettier uses a new heuristic to determine when to break method chains. You can see the heuristic in https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/6685/files#diff-207f1974ddc06ae7b574152f9afc878dR893.

Prettier breaks method chains if the arguments are non-trivial. A string literal is considered as "trivial", but an arrow function expression is considered as "non-trivial". That's the reason you're seeing different behaviour when you pass strings vs arrow functions as parameters.